# Automatically adding CD box art so that I can put it on my iPod

Tags: rhythmbox, ipod

I know it's possible to automatically find CD covers for albums, because rhythmbox is doing it on the fly. (When I listen to stuff, it finds the CD cover online...)

What I want is to get this information onto my ipod. As it stands pretty much all my songs have the default blank CD cover... I use gtkpod to transfer music to it.

This needs to be an automatic process, because I have a large music library and I'm lazy and it's not exactly an important thing...

I rip CDs I buy with the basic CD extractor, so all the files are in a Artist/Album/song.mp3 structure. (Yes I know, mp3 is evil, but iPod doesn't like `.ogg` so whatever)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice is to is Musicbrainz' Picard which is in the repository under 'picard'.

Once installed, install the "Cover Art Downloader" plugin, and set the settings to embed the artwork. Picard is great for fixing any bad metadata that may be on your music files, and it will download and the artwork for you.